# forcing RequireJS text! to reload

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Using the text! plugin, is there a way of forcing RequireJS to reload a file rather than returning the cached data?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plug-in? Have you tried anything? Did it fail, somehow?

Comment: the plugin is http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text

Comment: No, nothing is failing, it's actually as it should be. If you load a text file, any subsequent requests for that file return the originally loaded data. What I'm looking for is the odd case where that file might have changed and should be refreshed.

Comment: @nicholas did you find any proper solution for this? Seems quite annoying for users...

Answer (score 1):

RequireJS will only cache the file per request. A page reload will fetch it again.
If you see something different it is because:

- Either you have caching on your server.
- or your browser caches the request. You can of course disable this on your browser.

If you want browsers to fetch a clean file every time, you should have a no-cache header for these resources on your server.

Comment: to enforce browser loading files from server one could try to call them with randomy generated query string - like /Some-path-to-file/MyJSfile.js?v=TIMESTAMP

Comment: @shershen Don't think you can do that with require.js

Comment: @ggozad you can append a GET parameter to all module requests made with requirejs using requirejs.config({ urlArgs: 'getparam' }) -- this can be used to break browser caching

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could add the new html5 cache feature by providing a cache manifest: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

then you could use the requirejs "domReady" to get the proper load event:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

and then listen to the proper event (code taken from the first link):

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
  // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
  if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
} else {
  // Manifest didn't changed. Nothing new to server.
}}, false);
```

at this point whenever you update urlArgs you will get the new js files and with the manifest cache file you will get the new html files